# Use case of python function argument

Tags: python

I have a python function named `grids()` with keyword self in arguments, and another python function named `build_targets()`. I want to use `gridsize` and `anchor_vec` from `grids()` to another python function named `build_targets()`. Both functions are following:

```
def grids(self, img_size=(608,608), gridsize=(19, 19), device='cpu', type=torch.float32):

    nx, ny = gridsize  # x and y grid size
    self.nx = nx
    self.ny = ny

    if isinstance(img_size, int):
        self.img_size = int(img_size)
    else:
        self.img_size = max(img_size)

    self.stride = self.img_size / max(gridsize)

    yv, xv = torch.meshgrid([torch.arange(ny), torch.arange(nx)])

    self.register_buffer('grid_xy', torch.stack((xv, yv), 2).view((1, 1, ny, nx, 2)).to(device)) 


    self.anchor_vec = self.anchors.to(device) / self.stride
    self.register_buffer('gridsize',torch.Tensor(gridsize).to(device))


def build_targets(model, targets):

    for i in layers_list:
        ng, anchor_vec = gridsize, anchor_vec # from grids()
```

Is there any way to use `gridsize` and `anchor_vec` in `build_targets()` or how do I call it in `build_target()` function?

Any comments would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `self` is not a keyword. In your code, it is merely the name of the first argument to your methods. That is the convention in Python, since this argument gets passed the instance when a method is called from an instance.

Comment: are these functions of a class?

Comment: @luigigi, grid() function is not from class. I have been looking for a way to call it inside build_target() function

Comment: if `grids()` is not a function in a class, why do you have `self` as first argument? that does not make sense. also the calls `self.nx` in that method will not work because you try to reference to class variables (unless you pass an object as first argument when calling `grids` which is very unlikely). you should check out the basics to python classes. you probably want a class with both methods as functions in your class so you can write and access class variables like `anchor_vec` in your functions.

Comment: @luigigi thanks for your comments. Would you please check the link following [https://github.com/ming71/yolov3-pytorch/blob/13534b01f86cfadde3b8844e6391ca4fe1f0f082/testforcam/backup/models.py#L311], there is a function called create_grids() in line 311, I have been trying to use this function but my own way of implementing model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `grids()` is a method inside a class, then you have 2 choices:

1. Modify `build_targets()`, make it a method inside a class by adding `self` to its arguments:

```py
class SomeClass:
    def grids(...):
        self.gridsize = gridsize # (*)
        #some code

    def build_targets(self, model, targets):
        for i in layers_list:
            ng, anchor_vec = self.gridsize, self.anchor_vec # requires (*)
            # or
            ng, anchor_vec = (self.nx, self.ny), self.anchor_vec # does not requires (*)
```

Calling:

```py
some_instance.build_targets(some_model, some_targets)
```

2. Add more arguments to `build_targets()`:

```py
def build_targets(model, targets, gridsize, anchor_vec):
    for i in layers_list:
        ng, anchor_vec = gridsize, anchor_vec
```

Calling:

```py
build_targets(some_model, some_targets, (some_instance.nx, some_instance.ny), some_instance.anchor_vec)
# quite long line
```

By this way, `build_targets()` is "independent" to the class. Doing this is equivalent to moving `build_targets()` out of the class.